# mistaccaly created extra ssl certificate generate -> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: putty, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

i am very new to web hosting and
you can check my website https://www.potatino.com/,

it show error : NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

i am using digital-ocean

my certificates currently are:
[certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBjYT.png)

my mistake :
actually i was force renewing the certificates by this command

```
certbot -d potatino.com,www.potatino.com,dev.potatino.com --force-renewal
```

and other command like this for force renewel

but it generates other two certificates

so anyone can say how to delete extra certificates safely?

my older certifacates worked but it was expired so i am renewing it as seen in this picture
[my old certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NggQo.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably best to contact your web hosting service provider to issue a proper cert with both DNS domains listed in the subjectAltName (SAN).  Otherwise, either stop redirecting to 'www', or bind the other 'www' certificate to your secure HTTPS 443 listener -- both being temporary solutions.

Comment: _(Please don't screenshot terminal output, instead, please copy/paste the content into a code box.)_ **The `commonName` should not be a hostname/FQDN**, as these need to be specified in the SAN [`subjectAltName`] profile and browsers will generate errors if  SAN profiles are not used. Do you want four separate certs, as all those can be combined into one cert using a SAN profile with additional DNS values sets [`DNS.1`, `DNS.2`, etc.] when generating the CSR to send to a public CA for signing _(please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800) answer for additional info)_.