# OpenConnect certificate failed verfication: signer not found

Tags: networking, vpn, ssl, certificate, cisco-anyconnect

On Arch Linux.

School requiring use of a VPN. Installed [OpenConnect](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenConnect), running it as

```
openconnect vpn.xyz.edu
```

I get the following output

```
POST https://vpn.xyz.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found

Certificate from VPN server "vpn.xyz.edu" failed verification.
Reason: signer not found
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert pin-sha256:QY6jkD6lYNKQPM+m7wVLb7mMp1TflU8x6lKD6ULD2gA=
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:
```

I try the command again with the --servercert pin appended

```
openconnect vpn.xyz.edu --servercert=pin-sha256:QY6jkD6lYNKQPM+m7wVLb7mMp1TflU8x6lKD6ULD2gA=
```

I get the following output

```
POST https://vpn.xyz.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.xyz.edu with ciphersuite (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-SECP256R1)-(RSA-SHA512)-(AES-256-GCM)
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sat, 12 Mar 2022 05:58:01 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
XML response has no "auth" node
GET https://vpn.xyz.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.xyz.edu with ciphersuite (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-SECP256R1)-(RSA-SHA512)-(AES-256-GCM)
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Close
Date: Sat, 12 Mar 2022 05:58:01 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
Location: /+webvpn+/index.html
Set-Cookie: tg=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
HTTP body length:  (0)
GET https://vpn.xyz.edu/+webvpn+/index.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.xyz.edu with ciphersuite (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-SECP256R1)-(RSA-SHA512)-(AES-256-GCM)
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store
Set-Cookie: webvpn=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpn_as=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpnc=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpnlogin=1; secure
X-Transcend-Version: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
Please enter your username and password.
Username:
```

I enter the username and password prompt

```
Please enter your username and password.
Username:johndoe
Password:
```

It seems to go through, but the **Server certificate verify failed** pops up again and it just re-prompts me for my username and password.

```
POST https://vpn.xyz.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.xyz.edu with ciphersuite (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-SECP256R1)-(RSA-SHA512)-(AES-256-GCM)
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sat, 12 Mar 2022 06:03:59 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
XML response has no "auth" node
GET https://vpn.xyz.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.xyz.edu with ciphersuite (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-SECP256R1)-(RSA-SHA512)-(AES-256-GCM)
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Close
Date: Sat, 12 Mar 2022 06:03:59 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
Location: /+webvpn+/index.html
Set-Cookie: tg=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
HTTP body length:  (0)
GET https://vpn.xyz.edu/+webvpn+/index.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.xyz.edu
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.xyz.edu with ciphersuite (TLS1.2)-(ECDHE-SECP256R1)-(RSA-SHA512)-(AES-256-GCM)
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store
Set-Cookie: webvpn=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpn_as=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpnc=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpnlogin=1; secure
X-Transcend-Version: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
Please enter your username and password.
Username:johndoe
Password:
POST https://vpn.xyz.edu/+webvpn+/index.html
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store
Set-Cookie: webvpn=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpn_as=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpnc=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: webvpnlogin=1; secure
X-Transcend-Version: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
Please enter your username and password.
Username:
```

I enter my username and password again, and it repeats.
Sometimes however it doesn't repeat, but just shows a **POST** request with no further output.

```
Please enter your username and password.
Username:johndoe    
Password:
POST https://vpn.xyz.edu/+webvpn+/index.html
```

I tried googling the error, but the related threads haven't helped much as I'm new to VPNs and don't know how certification works, or what a "signer" is for that matter. Would appreciate any explanation.

Kernel: 5.16.13-arch1-1

Network Manager: iwd

Laptop Model: Asus M16 GU603

Comment: What do the school IT folks say?

Comment: The "signer" error would generally refer to the CA, as in the certificate is self-signed and lacks [Chain of Trust](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-certificate-authority/)

Comment: @JW0914 CA? Certificate Authority? Are you saying that this would be an error on my schools end rather than mine?

Comment: @MichaelMoreno If that's the case, yes, however I'm not familiar with this specific implementation of OpenVPN by Cisco [OpenConnect] _(all SSL VPNs are OpenVPN)_. To determine if the server cert is self-signed, this could be determined by the client log with verbosity set to `5` [`verb 5`] _(it should list the Distinguished Name of the server cert with verbosity set that high, then you can determine if the cert is self signed or if it has a CA / ICA that signed it)_, however I'm not sure if that's possible with OpenConnect since I've never used it. Is your client cert signed by a CA / ICA?

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ OpenVPN certs should _always_ be signed by a CA / ICA _(a self-generated one or a public authority)_, as not doing so opens the door wide open to a MITM attack. If the school is using a self-signed server cert, please share [this](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800) answer with them, as I cover how to create VPN certs with a CA or ICA within it, providing a link to a custom built [`openssl.cnf`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/Linux/openssl.cnf) that's easy to customize for creating the certs _(streamlined instructions begin on line 430)_